# how to use registerHotKeys function with Ctrl+Shift+d

Tags: c#, winapi, hotkeys

I'm setting up a hotkey in my code for Ctrl+Shift+d.  I've got it working now as Ctrl+d (almost there...), but I can't figure out how to get the second modifier (Shift) to work.  Below is the way I am calling the function currently for just Ctrl+d

```
Win32.RegisterHotKey(hWndSource.Handle, add, Win32.MOD_CONTROL, Win32.VK_KEY_D);
```

I want to use Win32.MOD_CONTROL and Win32.MOD_SHIFT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass `Win32.MOD_CONTROL | Win32.MOD_SHIFT` as the third parameter (instead of just `Win32.MOD_CONTROL`). It bitwise ORs the `CONTROL` and `SHIFT` values together in the modifier flags.

This is documented in the API page for the [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) function:

> The `fsModifiers` parameter can be a combination of the following values.

The bitwise OR (`|`) combines the `MOD_CONTROL` and `MOD_SHIFT` values into a single value with both bits set.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try it, but is there some obvious documentation for this?

Comment: See my edit above for a reference to the documentation. The purpose of the bitwise OR operator can be found in any programming reference.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) is a fairly good explanation of bitwise inclusive ORs and other operators.

Comment: It all makes sense. Thanks!  "Can be a combination of the following values" is a little ambiguous to me.

Comment: "Combination" means "one or more of", which means they can be combined. The way to combine them is a bitwise inclusive OR, which is what `|` in C/C#/C++/Java and several other languages use to indicate. Does that help? :)

Comment: lol yes thanks you!  I just didn't immediately think "bitwise or" when I read it.  Unfortunately I've been spoiled by the .NET documentation where things are a little more explicit